# Delete element from selenium table with known text

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm scraping websites with Selenium, and in doing so, the code I have written will fault if a certain text is discovered on the page (within the parameters). This text is known and consistent, so I'd like to implement into the code a removal of it. I've been trying to use .replace() with no luck, so wondering if there is a way in selenium to

```
names = driver.find_elements(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value="l-name")
```

but to explicitly exclude a result that populates with known text, "Alex" for example.

Any help?
Thank you!

Errors:

```
AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'replace'
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

Stuck further.

Comment: Is not clear what you want to get. The idea is that if an specific element contains the known text then the test must fail?

Comment: I'm scraping class "l-name", there are 40 results I want displayed and written to the file, but there is one that I don't want written, which is the exact same text every time. I can't just delete from the CSV since it's also using another class to identify and the two are linked, but with the one text line it screws with the rest of the correlating classes in the code, so I need to be able to isolate just that one sample of text and NOT display or write it.